# Relation between torsion in torsion free of covariant derivative and torsion free group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry

Is there a relationship between "torsion free" of covariant derivatives and the torsion free group? Or is this just coincidence that people use the term "torsion free" here? It is in general required for torsion free of covariant derivatives definition. I am not even sure about whether I phrased question correctly. If so, how do I realize the torsion module within?

Comment: No, there is no connection. ${}{}{}$